# Create a jest test to fail an async function which does not use await

Tags: javascript, jestjs

```
async function isContentUser (userEmail, studentStatus) {
  const hasContentAccess = getContentCreatorAccess()
  const hasContentStudentStatus = studentStatus === CONTENT

  return hasContentStudentStatus || hasContentAccess
}

async function getContentCreatorAccess () {
  const { contentCreatorAccess } = await api.getContentCreatorPermission()

  return contentCreatorAccess
}
```

As you can see in `isContentUser` function, we're not awaiting `getContentCreateAccess`, but the below existing test pass, because `hasContentAccess` in the return value is a promise and we're awaiting the promise in the test.

And I want to create a PR which adds `await` before `getContentCreatorAccess` call, how can I come up with a test which works with `await` but not in the current code.

```
  it(`should return true if studentStatus is not Content but user has content permission`, async () => {
    api.getContentCreatorPermission.mockResolvedValue({
      contentCreatorAccess: true
    })

    expect(await isContentUser('email@gmail.com', 'Audit')).toBe(true)
  })
```

Comment: did you ever figure out a solution? i'm having a similar issue